# Creating an offline store website for software in vb.net like Valve's steam or EA's origin

Tags: vb.net, steam

I am trying to create an offline store/website game manager program in vb.net that will essentially allow a user to browse through a computer game catalog and select an item for download. The functionality will be similar to Valve's Steam or EA's Origin software. At the moment i am using a web browser component to display the site.

The bit that i am stuck on is how to intercept the user's url clicks to raise an event in the vb.net outer program. Looking at steam it seems to use a special url (href="steam://run/258700"). Is there a way to associate the steam:// with my program?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do some research on registering a custom protocol handler. (`steam://` is a protocol, just like `http://` or `ftp://`. It's "custom" because it's not one of the standard protocols.)

Comment: Thanks Ken, i didn't realise that it required a protocol handler. I've found the information on msdn now after a quick google search :)

Comment: Glad I could help. (I'm not the one that downvoted, BTW.)